# Cells overlap Custom TableView Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to have a TableView with single Header(Which I thought would be a simple straightforward thing.)
The TableView style is `Plain`.
The cells are being scrolled above the header.
The cells are clearly above the Header so it isn't about clear background color.

I checked other similar questions but the solutions were futile.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    FinancialFieldHeader *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:[FinancialFieldHeader identifier]];
    header.lblLastDate.text = @"Header first line";
    header.lblUnitDetails.text = @"Header Second line"];

    return header;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 40.f;
}
```

I noticed if I return `nil` as header view the cells do not overlap and work as expected.

**UPDATE**
This is my FinancialHeader view.

```
@interface FinancialFieldHeader : UITableViewHeaderFooterView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLastDate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblUnitDetails;

+ (NSString*)identifier;
+ (void)registerForTable:(UITableView*)table;
@end
```

I found that anything except `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` works correctly (Cells do not overlap the header while scrolling).

Comment: is your tableview grouped?

Comment: Nope. The TableView is Plain.

Comment: make it group and then check?

Comment: I want the header to float. Plain style provides it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making `FinancialFieldHeader` as a `UIView` instead of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`